# error on Teamcity running command line custom script

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to run command line -custom script on Teamcity and getting this error (127):

```
[02:22:25][Step 1/1] /mnt/teamcity/temp/agentTmp/custom_script8657691082445726475: 1: /mnt/teamcity/temp/agentTmp/custom_script8657691082445726475: ./run.sh: not found
[02:22:25][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 127
[02:22:26][Step 1/1] Step run protractor test (Command Line) failed
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what solved it was adding 'Agent Requirements' (under build Configuration Settings) saying that 'system.agent.name' equals to the name of the Agent we use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some dependency of your script is not found where it expects it:

```
 ./run.sh: not found
```

Is that the actual script you are running? or is your script trying to call that script?